# I'm trying to create a button like in django

Tags: django, django-views

I have created a model and would like to use a like button afterwards
It did not work.How can I connect users and HTML with a function in views.py.

accounts.modles.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='likes',blank=True)
    profilepic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pic',blank=True)
```

likeme.views.py

```
def like_post(request):
    obj = get_object_or_404(UserProfile,id=request.POST.get('userprofile_id'))
    obj.likes.add(request.user)
    return redirect('profile_details')
```

likeme.ursl.py

```
path("like/",likeview.like_post,name="like_post")
```

like.html

```
    <form class="" action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ user.id }}" class="btn btn-info">Like</button>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put the user pk in the button. It's better to use a hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="userprofile_id" name="userprofile_id" value="{{ user.pk }}">
```